# Rails view just stops rendering part way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, view, will-paginate

I have a very boring paginated index view. For some reason it just stops rendering part way through if I set per_page to 30, although if I set it to 20 it's perfectly fine. It only goes up to 23 entries and then just stops, and the page options don't show up, either: the entire pagination div is just missing.  If I view the source no other data is included after that point, so it's not just a CSS thing, I'm pretty sure. All the closing tags are there, though, `</body>` and `</html>` etc.

Here's my controller method:

```
def index
    @visitor_entries = VisitorEntry.all.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
end
```

And the view is just the default Rails generated index page, with a few minor tweaks (formatting, showing the name of belongs_to fields, etc.), plus `<%= will_paginate @visitor_entries %>` at the end.

I'm not sure where to even look to figure out where it's going wrong. Would this be in the controller, the view, or the CSS? I wouldn't think CSS since the data isn't even there, so it's not like it's just not showing on the screen... I've googled and not found anything remotely like this.

Comment: For sure you just have less than 30 items in your db.

Comment: No, there are more than 30 items. It's not showing all of them.

Comment: Try removing the `all` from your code. That may be interacting with the pagination in an unexpected way. But really, I think @JohnnyKlironomos is right, and you probably have 23 items in your db. How many items do you have when you do 20 per page?

Comment: There were 32. I think it's a problem with the view though.